# How to improve Mule Application boot time?

Tags: esb, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

We have a monolith Mule application, initially, it used to take 3-4 mins to start but now as the number of flows has increased, it has started taking 12 mins + to start the application. Can anyone pls help me with best practices so that I can improve the existing flows and decrease the application boot time.

```
Total files in project - 310
The size of jar file is 111 MB
```

Also, What are the best practices that we can follow to improve performance of the application ?

Comment: MuleSoft applications and Mule applications are two different things. Please share the exact version of Mule and any details of the application (connectors and their versions, configurations, logs, etc). Note that Stackoverflow may not be the appropriate to troubleshoot complex configurations issues that depend on your environment. Also the question is pretty generic as it is. You should not expect specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the deployable application jar and the number of files are meaningless without context.

Usually the increase of startup time is related to the number of connector configurations. If each connector needs to connect to something, adding more adds more time at initialization. It also depends on what each connector does exactly at initialization of course.

You should look at initialization logs to try to understand what the application may be doing.

In a generic way I can only suggest to see if the connectors support pooling. You will need to do testing to see if it helps or not.

Also you should consider refactoring the application to split it into smaller applications. It may be just too big.